# Search nearest places from my current location in Android map

Tags: android, dictionary

In my android application I want to search 5 nearest places from my current location in a map.This parameters are used to set the boundaries  **lowerLeftLatitude, lowerLeftLongitude, upperRightLatitude, upperRightLongitude.**  But I don't know to set their values.

This codes gives 5 plces:

```
            try {
                List<Address> addressList =geocoder.getFromLocationName(staddress, 5);//, lowerLeftLatitude, lowerLeftLongitude, upperRightLatitude, upperRightLongitude;
                    if(adr.getCountryName()!=null)
                    str+=adr.getCountryName().toString();
                }
                Log.v(addressList.toString(),"result");
                editText.setText(addressList.toString());

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

How can I set these values for nearest places from my location **or** is any other way to to get the nearest places?

Comment: Your current code is giving you the 5 nearest addresses without specifying the bounding coordinates. So what else do you need?

Comment: yes what else do u need if you are getting 5 nearest address? be more specific about it

Comment: I want to get the places with in a specific radius..

Answer (score 4):

You can use Google api for that to get nearst locations based on the latitude and longitude. 
[Example](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere)

This google api will return neasrt locations based on your query/ parameters you passed.

[Study here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search). This study will be useful for you

Comment: Google api is still in experimental stage, i want something more reliable